# devise and rspec-rails - How to sign-in user in Request type specs (specs tagged with type: :request)?

Tags: devise, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

**Environment**

```
Rails 4.2.0
ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]
devise         3.4.1
rspec-core  3.2.2
rspec-rails   3.2.1
```

In my **/spec/rails_helper.rb** I have included **Devise** helpers for spec files tagged with `type: :controller` and `type: :request`

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:suite) do
    begin
      DatabaseCleaner.start
      FactoryGirl.lint
    ensure
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
  end

  config.around(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.cleaning do
      example.run # ==================> L-60
    end
  end

  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!

  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :request

end
```

With that config in place the `type: controller` specs runs fine. However when running `type: request` specs I am getting following error:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
 # /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@myapp/gems/devise-3.4.1/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb:24:in `setup_controller_for_warden'
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@simplyhomeapp/gems/database_cleaner-1.4.1/lib/database_cleaner/generic/base.rb:15:in `cleaning'
 # /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@simplyhomeapp/gems/database_cleaner-1.4.1/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:92:in `cleaning'
 # /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@simplyhomeapp/gems/database_cleaner-1.4.1/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in cleaning'
 # /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@simplyhomeapp/gems/database_cleaner-1.4.1/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `call'
 # /home/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@simplyhomeapp/gems/database_cleaner-1.4.1/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:87:in `cleaning'
 # ./spec/rails_helper.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/test_helpers.rb#L24 is following

```
def setup_controller_for_warden #:nodoc:
  @request.env['action_controller.instance'] = @controller  # ==================> L-24
end
```

I am aware that @request instance is not available for :request type specs and hence the error.

Are there any helpers available we can use to sign-in a user in :request type specs  when using Devise?

I found a similar issue https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1114, the [reply](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1114#issuecomment-1310379) to which suggests following:

> If you're doing integration tests, make sure to sign in your user in the tradicional way, by filling the sign in form and submitting.

But I would like to by pass the actual login for specs which requires a signed-in user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

With the help of a few SO posts(please refer to the **References** section below) I have managed to achieve the desired solution. I am posting my working code below, in case it can help others looking out for the same:

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ....
  ....
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers, type: :request
end
```

**spec/shared_contexts.rb**

```rb
RSpec.shared_context "api request global before and after hooks" do
  before(:each) do
    Warden.test_mode!
  end

  after(:each) do
    Warden.test_reset!
  end
end

RSpec.shared_context "api request authentication helper methods" do
  def sign_in(user)
    login_as(user, scope: :user)
  end

  def sign_out
    logout(:user)
  end
end
```

**/spec/requests/api/logout_spec.rb**

```rb
require 'rails_helper'
require 'shared_contexts'
      
RSpec.describe "Api Logout", :type => :request do
  include_context "api request authentication helper methods"
  include_context "api request global before and after hooks"

  let(:email) { 'test_user1@example.com' }
  let(:password) { 'password' }
        
  # Assumes you have FactoryGirl included in your application's test group.
  let!(:user) { create(:user, email: email, password: password) }

  context "DELETE /logout" do
    it "responds with 204 and signs out the signed-in user" do
      sign_in(user)

      # Till not figured out how to assert Warden has successfully logged in the user like we can do in a Devise controller spec by asserting subject.current_user. If anybody knows a way to do it please share.
      # expect(subject.current_user).to_not be_nil 

      delete "/logout"

      expect(response).to have_http_status(204)
    end
  end
end
```

I have still not figured out how to assert Warden has successfully logged in the user like we can do in a Devise controller spec by asserting `expect(subject.current_user).to_not be_nil`. If anybody knows a way to do it please share.

**References**

- [Integration test with rspec and devise sign_in env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779963/integration-test-with-rspec-and-devise-sign-in-env)
- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara
- https://github.com/hassox/warden/blob/master/lib/warden/test/helpers.rb
- [undefined method 'env' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932201/undefined-method-env-for-nilnilclass)
- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs

  > The code in the above link still relies on a request object which is only available in Controller specs. Thus not useful for `type: :request` specs.
- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3555

Thanks,

Jiggnesh

Comment: Hi Jiggneshh Gohel
Are you have some solution for:
expect(subject.current_user).to_not be_nil

Comment: @ViktorLeonets Sorry I don't have any solution right now because I didn't pursued it afterwards.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a solution to this for hours. I think there are other ways to structure this that might work better for me (I believe the same effect could be achieved with support helpers and macros for Request specs the way I've seen done with Controller specs in some of these examples. 

I still have a problem as I get "uncaught throw: Warden" but I have to solve that problem for my feature specs too.

Comment: I fixed the warden problem using 
` user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
login_as(user, :scope => :user, :run_callbacks => false) ` as per the docs at Devise "How to test with Capybara"

Comment: Not working here. It throws `cannot load such file -- shared_contexts`. I am using rspec 3.4.4 and rails 4.2.0. Any help?

Comment: @JeffreyC `shared_contexts` is a file in your application expected to be present at `<APP_ROOT>/spec/shared_contexts.rb`. Its clearly mentioned in the instructions in my answer. Hope that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

While the popular answer here, also replicated on the Devise wiki, is ok, it is simplest to just:

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
end
```

And just use `sign_in` in your request spec. This is the equivalent of declaring `include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers` in an system/feature spec or Rails system/controller test.

#### Reference

[Devise wiki: How to sign in and out a user in request type specs - Simple approach](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-sign-in-and-out-a-user-in-Request-type-specs-(specs-tagged-with-type:-:request)#1-simple-approach)

Comment: Thanks for sharing an update on this. It would have been more helpful if you could have shared the wiki link where you found your shared solution. I found it in Devise's [Readme](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#integration-tests). Also I checked that module [Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/test/integration_helpers.rb) is just a wrapper around the solution I shared. But still having an inbuilt thing definitely helps in cutting down the maintenance of custom helpers in an application. Thanks.

Comment: im getting [#<Proc:0x00005630eaf015d8@/home/humayun/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/test/helpers.rb:19>]
 on sign_in @user