# What could be causing Devise test helpers to not simulate a sign in of a user as expected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, minitest

I have been trying to convert an app with home-made authentication to one that uses Devise.  A main reason to do this is so that I can use the helper methods to simulate signing in a user in my tests.

I am able to sign in through a browser however I am not able to sign in a user in a test.

I have followed instructions on how to sign in:

test/test_helper.rb:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all

  # Returns true if a test user is logged in.
  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end

  # Log in as a particular user.
  def log_in_as(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers
  # Log in as a particular user.
  def log_in_as(user, password: 'password', remember_me: '1')
    post user_session_path, params: { user: { email: user.email,
                                          password: password
                                          # remember_me: remember_me
                                           } }
  end
end

class ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::TestHelpers
end
```

test/controllers/topics_controller_test.rb:

```
require 'test_helper'

class TopicsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @topic = topics(:one)
    @user = users(:archer)
    @admin = users(:michael)
    @member = registrations(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    sign_in @user
    get topics_url
    assert_response :success
  end
```

topics/controller:

```
class TopicsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # GET /topics
  def index
    @topics = Topic.where.not(workflow_state: "rejected").order("updated_at DESC").narrow_down_search(params[:search]).paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

but It keeps saying it is redirecting.

```
 FAIL["test_should_get_index", #<Minitest::Reporters::Suite:0x00007f9e43a995f0 @name="TopicsControllerTest">, 0.9262119999984861]
 test_should_get_index#TopicsControllerTest (0.93s)
        Expected response to be a <2XX: success>, but was a <302: Found> redirect to <http://www.example.com/users/sign_in>
        Response body: <html><body>You are being <a href="http://www.example.com/users/sign_in">redirected</a>.</body></html>
        test/controllers/topics_controller_test.rb:15:in `block in <class:TopicsControllerTest>'
```

the same happens with RSpec tests if i follow the instructions [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/devise/2.2.8#test-helpers)

```
1) TopicsController#index responds sucsessfully
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
       expected the response to have status code 200 but it was 302
```

Comment: Is this RSpec or MiniTest?

Comment: setting `session[:user_id]` is not actually simulating a Devise login. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29510570/1880203